# NSDateFormatter with region format

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I use this code to process a date string coming in from a json feed:

```
NSDateFormatter * formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateStyle: NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
[formatter setFormatterBehavior: NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];
[formatter setDateFormat: @"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss +0000"];
```

so if I call

```
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString: @"Tue, 08 Sep 2009 19:21:27 +0000"];
```

I get back a usable date if my region format is United States or United Kingdoms, but if I set it to Germany it returns nil. I understand there are some differences in behaviors across different locales, but if I define a format shouldn't that correct for any inconsistencies?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Names like "Tue" and "Sep" are English.  Other languages use different names.

If you want to be able to parse English dates independent of the device's region settings, set your DateFormatter's locale to **`en_US`** using the **`-setLocale:`** method.

Comment: thanks it's done :)

datePicker.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];

Or For Device Go to bellow Path & Change Your Region if not Set as you required
Setting >>  general >> International >> Region Formate >> (Select) United States

Comment: Thanks this helped me solve a major crash issue with my app. For users with different regional format.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks fixed it up with:
    [formatter setLocale:[[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"US"] autorelease]];