# NSDateFormatter and NSDate Issue

Tags: nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a date string that need to be converted to a NSDate, here is the string "Fri Aug 17 12:23:40 +0800 2012",

here is my covert code,

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
//formatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
formatter.dateFormat = @"EEE MMM dd H:mm:ss ZZZ yyyy";

NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:dateStr];
NSLog(@"%@", date);
```

I think my code is fine, but date is null. and I don't know why, can anybody help?

Comment: Your code is fine, I tried it on my system, and it produced `2012-08-17 04:23:40 +0000` NSLog output. Perhaps it has to do with your local settings (`Fri` and `Aug` are not too internationally-friendly strings).

Comment: yes, this code works on my own mbp, but today, its not running on my corp mbp. both MBPs are running mountain lion now. don't know why.

Comment: Their system may be set to a non-English locale.

Comment: Make a `NSDate` object, pass it to your `formatter`'s `stringFromDate:` method, and see what values it produces. This should provide an explanation for you.

Comment: Yes, it's the non-English thing. I changed the region to "United States", and it's working now. Thanks. but how to deal with this situation without change the region manually?

Comment: Here is a link to [an answer to your last question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1395912/335858).

Comment: great, thanks! do u mind put your comment into an ANSWER? so I can MARK it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code produced `2012-08-17 04:23:40 +0000` output on my system, so perhaps the problem has to do with your regional settings. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1396138/335858) provides information on how to make a date formatter that is independent of the local region settings of your system.